# Why using HttpClient in a using block IS WRONG in WebApi context?

Tags: c#, httpclient, using, webapi

So, the question is why the usage of HttpClient in using block is WRONG, BUT in WebApi context?

I've been reading this article [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In it we have the following example:

```
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
  // (real-world code shouldn't use HttpClient in a using block; this is just example code)
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
  }
}

// My "top-level" method.
public class MyController : ApiController
{
  public string Get()
  {
    var jsonTask = GetJsonAsync(...);
    return jsonTask.Result.ToString();
  }
}
```

The comment `// (real-world code shouldn't use HttpClient in a using block; this is just example code)` just triggered me. I've been always using HttpClient in this way.

The next thing I've checked is [Microsoft's documentation on HttpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2).
In it, we have the following statement with provided source sample:

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout
> the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for
> every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy
> loads. This will result in SocketException errors. Below is an example
> using HttpClient correctly.

```
public class GoodController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient;

    static GoodController()
    {
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

So isn't the constructor called on each request and thus a new HttpClient will be created every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a bit of a long answer to this...

Originally, the official recommendation was to use `HttpClient` in a `using` block. But this [caused problems at scale](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), essentially using up lots of connections in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

So, the official recommendation changed to use a static `HttpClient`. But this caused problems where [it would never correctly handle DNS updates](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18348).

So, the ASP.NET team came up with [`IHttpClientFactory` in .NET Core 2.1](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore), so code (or at least code running on modern platforms) can reuse `HttpClient` instances (or, more properly, the *message handlers* of those instances), avoiding the `TIME_WAIT` problem, but also periodically closing those connections to avoid the DNS problem.

But, at the same time, the .NET team came up with [`SocketsHttpHandler` also in .NET Core 2.1](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core), which *also* does connection pooling.

So, on modern platforms, you can either use `IHttpClientFactory` or a static/singleton `HttpClient`. On older platforms (including .NET Framework), you would use a static/singleton `HttpClient` and either live with the DNS issue or [use other workarounds](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html).

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Truly there was more to that than I anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually writing this question I noticed the **static constructor** in the code sample provided from Microsoft. This all makes sense now.

The [Static Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) are used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed only once. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

In the context of WebAPI the static constructor is called **one time only** thus creating only one HttpClient and reusing it for all other requests.

I'll never use `using(HttpClient....)` in production code again.

This is a great article on the wrong usage of HttpClient - [YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Also see the excellent articles: [You're Using HttpClient Wrong](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx) , [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://www.westerndevs.com/Deployment/httpclientwrong/) , [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: Thanks, just remembered another nice article related to the topic.